# Can RabbitMQ "disk free monitoring" be enabled?

Tags: rabbitmq

In response to this curl to the RabbitMQ Management API ...

curl localhost:15672/api/nodes/{node name}/ -u {user} | jq .

... after typing the password, I am getting a response that includes this line ...

"disk_free_limit": "disk_free_monitoring_disabled",

How can I enable this, or is it a build-time choice or platform limitation?

I am using RabbitMQ 3.6.6 on CentOS release 6.8 (Final).

UPDATE: I just noticed this erlang startup flag (using ps -ef | grep rabbit):

-os_mon start_disksup false

That turned out to be unrelated. It is set by rabbitmq-server that way, even in installations where I don't get the problem.

Comment: can you check the logs and see if there is this `"Disabling disk free space monitoring"` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The log shows normal startup, without this message.

Comment: This is unlikely to be unanswered as I no longer have access to the environment where it was occurring.

As a final detail for anyone else who runs into this, I should mention the CentOS 6.8 environment where I saw this was running under VirtualBox on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

you get this error when  `rabbit_disk_monitor` can't execute:

```
/bin/df -kP ++ dir
```

check the logs, maybe is a permission problem and or try to execute `/bin/df -kP` and see the result

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can run /bin/df -kP on this box without trouble, as the rabbitmq user. But what is "dir"? Is it the Mnesia directory?

Comment: Strange, I saw that you are using an old rabbitmq version (`3.3.6`) cam you try with one of the last one ? (ex: `RabbitMQ 3.6.9` )

Comment: I am sorry, that was a typo. I am using 3.6.6 on CentOS 6.8. I will go correct that above. Also, that same 3.6.6 release on MacOS doesn't behave this way.